# How to calculate max population size?

Tags: statistics

Suppose you have an initial population of size $N$.  It takes two members of the population to breed and each member of the population can breed a maximum of $x$ times.  Members of the population never die.

How can you calculate the theoretical maximum population size ($MP$)?

A few cases:

1. $N = 2; x = 0 \\ MP = N = 2$
2. $N = 2; x = 1 \\ MP = N + \frac N2 = 2 + 1 = 3$
3. $N = 4; x = 1 \\ MP = N + \frac N2 + \frac N4 = 4 + 2 + 1 = 7$
4. $N = 6; x = 1 \\ MP = N + floor(\frac N2) + floor(\frac N4)  + floor(\frac N8) = 6 + 3 + 1 + 0 = 10$
5. $N = 8; x = 1 \\ MP = N + floor(\frac N2) + floor(\frac N4)  + floor(\frac N8) = 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 15$

Is there a general formula for $ N \geq 0$ and $x \geq 0$?

Comment: If you're downvoting please mention what needs to be improved

Comment: Assuming N > 1 and x > 0, wouldn't this be infinite since no one ever dies? If you meant maximum over a given time, how often can members of the population breed? I'm guessing you're going to get exponential growth with a recursion of some sort

Comment: @barrycarter Assuming x was 2, wouldn't the total be N + (N/2)? You have the original population of N plus 1/2 the population of N breeds with the other half to generate one spawn. At least that's my initial thoughts. Oh but then the N/2 can all breed with each other to generate N/4 and so on. Would that be infinite?

Comment: If N=x=2, 0th generation would yield two children for 4 total. The two children would now breed twice so the 2nd generation would have 6 total. The grandchildren would now breed so the 3rd generation would have 8 total. And so on. Are you limiting to a certain number of generations?

Comment: @barrycarter yes sorry meant to use x equals 1 as my example. No maximum on number of generations. But a given population member can only breed x times. But the number available to breed keeps getting smaller as each generation only produces half the offspring since two parents are required to generate one offspring.

Comment: So take base case of N=2 and x=1 then 2 parents breed once and generate a single offspring. The population is done as the offspring has no one to breed with and the parents have each used up their single breeding. So the population max would be 3

Comment: With x=1, this is an interesting question. It's upper bounded by two times N, but I don't think there's a clean formula for it (I'm probably wrong). For example, you can't just add N + floor(N/2) + floor(N/4) + floor(N/8) + ... because you'd have leftovers that can breed with each other. This may have something to do with the number of 1s in the binary representation of N, with each pair of 1s giving an additional offspring. If you work it out, search OEIS to see if it's a known sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As barrycarter has noted, if $x > 1$, the answer is always $\infty$. You've noted that the problem is trivial when $x = 0$. It is also trivial when $N = 1$, So assume $N > 1$. The remaining case is $x = 1$.

When $N$ is a power of $2$, it is simple enough: The first $N = 2^k$ members produce $2^{k-1}$ children, which produce $2^{k-2}$ children, and so on, for a total population of $$2^k + 2^{k-1} + \dots + 2 + 1 = 2^{k+1} - 1 = 2N - 1$$

When $N$ is not a power of $2$, just break them up into groups that are powers of two, and let them reproduce until they run down:
$$N = 2^{e_1} + 2^{e_2} + ... + 2^{e_n}$$
yields $$2^{e_1+1} - 1 + 2^{e_2+1} -1 + ... + 2^{e_n+1}-1 = 2N - n$$
as a population. But it doesn't end there, as each group stops because the final single offspring has no one to mate with. Thus you can now gather these $n$ unmated offspring and do the same thing with them.

One method to break $N$ into powers of two is to write it in binary. Each $1$ corresponds to a power of two. The number of groups will be the number of $1$s in the binary representation of $N$. Call that $\beta(N)$.

So the first grouping results in a population of $2N - \beta(N)$. But it leaves $\beta(N)$ unmatched members for a second grouping (putting the $2N - 2\beta(N)$ already mated members aside). The second grouping grows to a population of $2\beta(N) - \beta^2(N)$. The total population is becomes $$(2N - 2\beta(N)) + (2\beta(N) - \beta^2(N)) = 2N - \beta^2(N)$$
With $\beta^2(N)$ unmated members. Continuing increases the population to $2N - \beta^3(N)$, and so on.

But $\beta(1) = 1$, and for all $n > 1, 1\le \beta(n) < n$, so eventually $\beta^k(N)$ must decrease until for some $k, \beta^k(N) = 1$.

Thus the maximum population will always be $2N - 1$.

Comment: Ahh, the driveby downvoter strikes again. It is quite sad really. Young children experiment with blindly attacking others without explanation, but as they grow, most figure out how unproductive this is, and learn to communicate instead when they have problems. But an unfortunate few never manage to grasp this simple fact, carrying this childish behavior even in their adult years. They are to be pitied, but cannot be respected.

Comment: I now realize if x > 1 the result would be infinite, but what would the formula look like of that infinite sequence (even if just for even numbered populations)?

Comment: If $x\ne 2$ is even, then each new generation is $\frac x2$ times the size of the previous generation, so the total population after the $k$-th generation is $$N + N\left(\frac x2\right) + N\left(\frac x2\right)^2 + \dots + N\left(\frac x2\right)^{k-1} = \frac{N(x^k - 2^k)}{2^{k-1}(x - 2)}$$When $x = 2$, each new generation has $N$ members, so after $k$ generations, the population is $Nk$. When $x$ is odd, it becomes a lot more complicated, but asymptotically approaches the even $x$ formula.